# How to show WordPress Related Post in two column.

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add Related post on my WordPress blog site in `single.php` but it shows in a long Column is there any way to shows in 2 column ?

**Here Is My code**

```
<?php
$orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$term = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
if ($term) {
$cat_ids = array();
foreach($term as $individual_cat) $cat_ids[] = $individual_cat->term_id;
$args=array(
'cat_in' => $cat_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=>4, // Number of related posts to display.
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post();
?>
<div class="relatedthumb">
 <ul>
    <li><a rel="external" href="<? the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(55,55)); ?><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<?php }
}
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

**Here is the Image What I want**
[image]

Please help !

Answer (score 1):

You can make it with CSS. Add to your CSS-file next code:

```
.relatedthumb > ul:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
.relatedthumb > ul > li {
  width:50%;  //You need to check that, if does not work - change it to 45%;
  float:left;
}
```